# Magento, add custom url. Xml or Php/Html

Tags: xml, magento

Example: within the catalogsearch.xml, i can found:

```
    <reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms">
            <label>Search Terms</label>
            <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" />
            <title>Search Terms</title>
        </action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch">
            <label>Advanced Search</label>
            <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
            <title>Advanced Search</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

It's clear. Within the "footer_links" block, the code will add 2 urls, Search and Advanced Search links. Now, my question is: why should i add these 2 links through the xml layout file instead of adding them directly inside the phtml template related to the footer?!

I think, if it's the same, it there is no convenience to prefer one method instead to the other one, i would do it editing the phtml file.

Comment: what would be when you select new theme. your all code gone.Only xml works generic for all themes as for i know.

Comment: Its also a good way od separating the view stuff and the real business logic. Adding links or removing blocks or whatever can be done by somebody and coding real business logic can be done by somebody else. If you work with Magento you should do it the Magento way, which is, adding the links via xml.

Comment: Mahmood Rehman: I think your reply is completely wrong. Suppose i should delete that footer_links reference within catalogsearch.xml. If i change theme, now, in which no new catalogsearch.xml file exist, do you think those links will magically appears again? The reply is NO. So, xml layout files are not cross-theme at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few blocks in Magento which act as kind of 'containers' for child blocks to be added to from other layout files.  They are generally defined in the `page.xml` layout file, as is the case with the `footer_links` block:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
```

As you can see this instantiates block class `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` which contains the `addLink()` block method the layout file calls in the `<action>` tag.

Defining these kinds of blocks gives you great versatility in setting content to be added across multiple layout files.  Not only does this keep the block declarations separated into different layout files relevant just to particular modules, it can also be theme dependant allowing you to change the layout entirely between themes.

Also, if you move away from using blocks, which is basically what your are doing to some extent by working only in a template file, dependant on how that block is constructed and what children it has, you can lose some of the benefits of caching block HTML.

So working in the template file directly has 3 main drawbacks:

- You lose the benefit of using theme specific layout handles
- Template files are not kept nearly so clean
- You can lose some block caching benefits

I know that when fairly new to Magento working in the template files can seem like a good solution in a situation like this, but as you discover more about the Magento layout and how it functions, you will begin to see the massive benefits of working within the standards set by the framework - in this case using the layout files.  If you understand the benefits of having top level container blocks such as `content`, `header` and `footer`, exactly the same benefits apply with the `footer_links` block.